# Change position of days and hours

Tags: jquery, html, fullcalendar

In the calendar FullCalendar (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) is possible to change the position of days to hours (what i mean is where is the days is the hours, and where is the hours is the days.) in the week/day calendar?

Like this example http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/sample_timeline.shtml

Comment: Check this out http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=490

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no built in way to do it.

You will need to create a custom view.  You can base it off the agenda week view:
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/views/agendaWeek/

Comment: yes is that view i want it, but what i need to do if i used this calendar is to change the position labels days <-> hours.  How can i create a custom view? just like a timeline

Comment: like this http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/sample_timeline.shtml is possible?

Comment: You will need to download the code, see how they create the view and do it yourself with the changes.  It will most likely not be a trivial change.